# Regex: Find last occurrence of digit pair

Tags: regex

I'm trying to find the last match of a digit pair in some kinds of strings like these:

```
123f64swfW68F43
123f64swfW6843
123f64swfW6843sad
123f64swfW6843sa3d
```

In all of them the matching result should be 43. I tried my best and came to:

```
/(\d{2})(?!.*\d)/
```

But this works only for the first three strings.

Please note that I want to do this in one regular expression and without any further scripting.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Try [`.*(\d{2})(?!.*\1)`](https://regex101.com/r/Lqkzcm/1) and grab Group 1 value.

Comment: Unfortunatly it doesn't work: regexr.com/3sbkj

Comment: It does work because it [*captures* the value](https://regex101.com/r/Lqkzcm/1).

Comment: Oh I see. This may helps. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\d{2}(?!\d|.*\d{2})
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lqkzcm/6). It basically means "match 2 consecutive digits that are not immediately followed with a digit and that not followed with any 2 consecutive digits anywhere to the right of those two digits".

**Details**

- `\d{2}` - two digits
- `(?!\d|.*\d{2})` - that are not followed with a digit or with any two digits aftr any 0+ chars other than line break chars.

Alternatively, you may use

```
/.*(\d{2})/
```

and grab Group 1 value. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lqkzcm/3). This regex means "match all text it can to the last two digits, and capture the two digits in a separate memory buffer".

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `(\d{2})` - Capturing group 1: two digits

Comment: Do you really need the `(?!.*\1)` here? I cannot see a case where this might ever invalidate a previous match.

Comment: @SebastianProske Well, a good question. Looks like this check if redundant. It would be necessary to find *multiple* last occurrences of double digits, like in [`/(\d{2})(?!.*\1)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/Lqkzcm/2)

Comment: @SebastianProske I found another way to match those 2 digits without capturing.